# Moving to uninitialized memory, or how raw_storage_iterator works

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to move a range of objects into uninitialized memory (using move-construction). Since there is no move-counterpart to `std::uninitialized_copy`, I came up with two options: either use `std::move` with `raw_storage_iterator`, or resort to the manual loop:

```
T* dest = get_memory();
// option one
std::move(first, last, std::raw_storage_iterator<T*, T>(dest));
// option two
for (auto i=first; i != last; ++i, ++dest)
{
    new(dest) T(std::move(*i));
}
```

Will the first option do the move-construction (thus being equivalent to the second), or copy construction, or default construction followed by move assignment? Are there other considerations to prefer one option or another?

Comment: How std::move(it, it, it) supposed to work? Just curious. Always thought that std::move is basically a cast

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: There are two 2 things named `std::move`. There is one in the `<utility>` header, which takes a single argument, and does what you are referring to (cast to rvalue reference). There is another one in the `<algorithm>` header which takes 3 arguments, move assigns a range of values (analogous to what `std::copy` does with copy assignment).

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2127

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Cool! thank you. Well, isn't raw_storage_iterator only knows how to do copy-construction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::raw_storage_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/raw_storage_iterator) uses a *placement-new* operator on assignment which in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) defined in terms of a copy-assignment operator taking a const lvalue reference:

§ 20.7.10 [storage.iterator]/p1:

```
raw_storage_iterator& operator=(const T& element);
```

which always calls a copy constructor (even when invoked with an rvalue).

This case has been reported as [**LWG issue 2127**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2127) which adds support for move-constructible types by introducing another assignment operator taking an rvalue reference, meaning it **will be** possible to move-construct elements to an uninitialized memory once the proposed change is adopted. Until that update takes place, you need to rely on your own for-loop. Alternatively, you could leverage the [`std::uninitialized_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) algorithm defined as follows:

§ 20.7.12.2 [uninitialized.copy]/p1:

```
for (; first != last; ++result, ++first)
    ::new (static_cast<void*>(&*result))
        typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type(*first);
```

Once you wrap your input iterators using the [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) helper function, you'll get the same effect as your hand-written for-loop:

```
std::uninitialized_copy(std::make_move_iterator(first)
                      , std::make_move_iterator(last)
                      , dest);
```

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) extends the set of algorithms by introducing [`std::uninitialized_move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_move):

```
std::uninitialized_move(first, last, dst);
```

Comment: How about `uninitialized_copy` paired with `move_iterator`?

Comment: @T.C. Oh, I did not think about `uninitialized copy` + `move_iterator`, thanks! This looks the cleanest solution.